# sql: generate columns based on values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a table with data like

```
 pr     inv    comm  comm1   comm2
 123    1       10    0        1
 234    1       20    5        10
 345    1       40    16       21
 098    2       23    65       76
 765    2       45    32       0
 981    1       65    87       9
 981    2       45    32       100
```

i want the result as

```
 pr    comm    comm1   comm2     comm    comm1    comm2
         1       1     1         2        2        2 
 123     10      0      1        0        0        0
 234     20      5      10       0        0        0
 345     40      16     21       0        0        0
 098     0        0     0        23       65       76
 765     0        0     0        45       32       0 
 981     65      87     9        45       32       100
```

what i mean is i have to generate new columns for each and every `inv` column values.

Comment: Exactly which DBMS you are using ? the method of accomplish above task is vary in each. Not possible to answer for all in one.

Comment: sql server 2014

Comment: You can use PIVOT in SQL server and I think you can do it by using web so please try it once. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx I think you have to review your requirement first because it's not exactly what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going Dynamic.  This approach does require a helper function to convert your data into an EAV structure (Entity Attribute Value).

```
Declare @YourTable table (PR int,Inv int,Comm int,Comm1 int,Comm2 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(123,1,10, 0,  1),
(234,1,20, 5, 10),
(345,1,40,16, 21),
(098,2,23,65, 76),
(765,2,45,32,  0),
(981,1,65,87,  9),
(981,2,45,32,100)

Select PR=Entity
      ,Inv
      ,Col = Concat(B.Attribute,'_',Inv)
      ,B.Value
Into  #Temp
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) Where Attribute<>'Inv' ) B

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select @SQL = @SQL+','+QUOTENAME(Col)+'=max(IIF(Col='''+col+''',Value,0))' From (Select Top 100 Percent Inv,Col from #Temp Group By Inv,Col Order by Inv) A
Exec('Select PR'+@SQL+' From #Temp Group By PR Order By Pr')
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-EAV](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    with cteKey(k) as (Select Top 1 xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') From @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow) Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt))    

    Select Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(50)')
          ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
    From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
    Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt)
    Where xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Not In (Select k From cteKey)
)
/*
-- Notes:  First Field in Query will be the Entity
```

Answer (score 1):

At first UNPIVOT data then do a PIVOT, if there are many `inv`s better use dynamic SQL to generate and run your query:

```
SELECT  pr,
        COALESCE(inv1_comm,0) as inv1_comm,
        COALESCE(inv1_comm1,0) as inv1_comm1,
        COALESCE(inv1_comm2,0) as inv1_comm2,
        COALESCE(inv2_comm,0) as inv2_comm,
        COALESCE(inv2_comm1,0) as inv2_comm1,
        COALESCE(inv2_comm2,0) as inv2_comm2
FROM (
    SELECT  pr,
            'inv'+CAST(inv as nvarchar(max))+'_'+comms as inv_comms,
            [values]
    FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    ) as t
    UNPIVOT (
        [values] FOR comms IN (comm,comm1,comm2)
    ) as unpv
) as p
PIVOT (
    MAX([values]) FOR inv_comms IN (inv1_comm,inv1_comm1,inv1_comm2,inv2_comm,inv2_comm1,inv2_comm2)
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
pr  inv1_comm   inv1_comm1  inv1_comm2  inv2_comm   inv2_comm1  inv2_comm2
98  0           0           0           23          65          76
123 10          0           1           0           0           0
234 20          5           10          0           0           0
345 40          16          21          0           0           0
765 0           0           0           45          32          0
981 65          87          9           45          32          100
```

Explanation:

At first UNPIVOT part

```
SELECT  pr,
        'inv'+CAST(inv as nvarchar(max))+'_'+comms as inv_comms,
        [values]
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
) as t
UNPIVOT (
    [values] FOR comms IN (comm,comm1,comm2)
) as unpv
```

Generate this:

```
pr  inv_comms   values
123 inv1_comm   10
123 inv1_comm1  0
123 inv1_comm2  1
234 inv1_comm   20
234 inv1_comm1  5
234 inv1_comm2  10
345 inv1_comm   40
345 inv1_comm1  16
345 inv1_comm2  21
etc...
```

So we get all `comms` in one column from 3(N) columns.

Then we do PIVOT to get expanded by `inv`s result-set.

[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is needed to make `NULL` values - `0`

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.